# awk after grep: print value when grep returns nothing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a question when I use awk and grep to parse log files.
The log file contains some strings with figures, e.g.

```
Amount: 20
Amount: 30.1
```

And I use grep to parse the lines with keyword "Amount", and then use awk to get the amount and do a sum:

the command is like:

`cat mylog.log | grep Amount | awk -F 'Amount: ' '{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'`

It works fine for me. However, sometimes the mylog.log file does not contains the keyword 'Amount'. In this case, I want to print 0, but the above awk command will print nothing. How can I make awk print something when grep returns nothing?

Comment: `awk -F 'Amount: ' 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'`

Comment: You never need `grep` with `awk` and you never need `cat` with either one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk '/^Amount/ {amount+=$2} END {print amount+0}' file
```

With the `+0` trick you make it print `0` in case the value is not set.

#### Explanation

There is no need to grep + awk. awk alone can grep (and many more things!):

- `/^Amount/ {}` on lines starting with "Amount", perform what is in `{}`.
- `amount+=$2` add field 2's value to the counter "amount".
- `END {print amount+0}` after processing the whole file, print the value of `amount`. Doing `+0` makes it print `0` if it wasn't set before.

Note also there is no need to set 'Amount' as the field separator. It suffices with the default one (the space).

#### Test

```
$ cat a
Amount: 20
Amount: 30.1
$ awk '/^Amount/ {amount+=$2} END {print amount+0}' a
50.1

$ cat b
hello
$ awk '/^Amount/ {amount+=$2} END {print amount+0}' b
0
```

Answer (score 2):

If your line only contains "Amount: 20" then use @fedorqui's solution, but if it's more like "The quick brown fox had Amount: 20 bananas" then use:

```
awk -F'Amount:' 'NF==2{sum+=$2} END{print sum+0}' file
```

Comment: I tried and `-F'Amount:'` alone works on my `GNU Awk 4.1.0`. I guess that trailing spaces get removed while doing integer calculations.

Comment: @fedorui you're right but s/trailing/leading/ in this case. I'll update it. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answer! This is really an "extended" solution to my questions. I would like to mark both your solution and @fedorqui's as the best answer, but unfortunately I can only mark one.

Comment: If I have multiple keywords, how should I use awk? e.g. I want to find the lines contains both "fox" and "amount", and sum up the value after "Amount:"?

Comment: @Starry one solution would be to use `awk -F'Amount:' '/fox/ && NF==2{sum+=$2} END{print sum+0}' file`. By adding `/fox/` you indicate that the record (line) has to contain this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Awk one-liner,

```
awk -F 'Amount: ' '/Amount:/{print "1";sum+=$2}!/Amount:/{print "0"}END{print sum}' file
```

The above awk command would print the number 1 for the lines which has the string `Amount` and it prints `0` for the lines which don't have the string `Amount`. And also if the string `Amount` is found on a line then it stores the value(column 2) to the `sum` variable and adds it with any further values. Finally the value of the variable `sum` is printed at the last.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
Amount: 20
Amount: 30.1
foo bar
adbcksjc
sbcskcbks
cnskncsnc
$ awk -F 'Amount: ' '/Amount:/{print "1";sum+=$2}!/Amount:/{print "0"}END{print sum}' file
1
1
0
0
0
0
50.1
```